# Recuperar nome e email do usuário no NavigationDrawer?

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, firebase

Como faço para recuperar o nome e o e-mail do usuário logado? Está dando erro no código.Estou utilizando BD Firebase.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TextView nomePefil, emailPerfil;
private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
private DatabaseReference firebase;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //Recuperar Nome e E-mail para o Menu

    nomePefil = findViewById(R.id.tv_nomePerfil);
    emailPerfil = findViewById(R.id.tv_emailPerfil);

    autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String email = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();

    //>>>>>>>> erro aqui <<<<<<<<<<
    emailPerfil.setText(email);

    firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebase.child("usuarios").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String nome = postSnapShot.child("nome").getValue().toString();
                nomePefil.setText(nome);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Mostre o código que você está utilizando para criar o NavigationDrawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estiver usando o NavigationDrawer que o template já fornece:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    // Obtém a referência dos TextViews a partir do NavigationView 
    TextView text1 = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.text2);

    text1.setText("meu_texto");
    text2.setText("meu_texto");
```

Para recuperar do firebase faça:

```
private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String email = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
```

Para o nome, ele deve estar salvo em algum nó, para recuperar os valores você faz assim:

```
private DatabaseReference referenciaFirebase;
 referenciaFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

//Em "usuarios" eu ordeno tudo pelo email onde o email for igual ao meu email, então aí eu tenho todo o meu nó a disposição para recuperar os dados
referenciaFirebase.child("usuarios").orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String nome = postSnapshot.child("nome").getValue().toString();


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

"Usuarios" é o nome do nó principal, você coloca o seu, a partir dele eu ordeno a lista onde o email for igual ao meu email que eu já peguei, então dentro do for eu consigo recuperar qualquer valor de nó dentro desse usuário.

LEMBRANDO - você deve ter salvo em seu nó o email do usuário, caso contrário essa query não irá funcionar, caso não tenha salvo, use outra coisa que só aquele usuário tem para conseguir recuperar somente ele dentro do `for`

No exemplo que fiz olhe como está do db:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: fiz exatamente como falou mas está dando um erro que encaminha para : emailPerfil.setText(email); quando clica no console Run. Postei o código acima.

Comment: O usuário já está logado?

Comment: Se não estiver vai retornar null

Comment: Sim. Está logado.

Comment: Dê um Log na variável email, veja se ela está como null, se estiver, o usuário não está logado

Comment: Não precisa converter para String o getEmail?

Comment: Na verdade não, ele já retorna uma string, mas se quiser colocar o `toString()`, fique a vontade

Comment: Vai que dar certo

Comment: Descobri o seu erro, você referenciou os textview de maneira errada, no meu exemplo primeiro eu crio uma view e a partir dela eu faço a referência, olha la em cima como eu fiz

Comment: Na hora de setar o texto, o seu textview tem uma referência nula, e não o valor do texto nulo

Comment: Pode olhar aí, são as primeiras linhas da resposta

Comment: deu certo amigo. Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: ;) d nada, precisar tamo aí